# How can I call a member function of an object in main.cpp from a Qt button?

Tags: c++, qt, class

I am using Qt and have a start/stop button on the GUI. When the application opens, I call some code like this in my main.cpp file:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

Something something;
something.start();
```

In the mainwindow.cpp file that was created by Qt, I have this function that is called when the stop button is pressed:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_released()
{
    std::cout << "stopped" << std::endl;
}
```

How can I call `something.stop()` from `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_released()`? Or how can I restructure my code so that I can access that class instance?

Comment: Time to have a look at Qt Widget examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets.html and also read on Qt signal-slot.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this problem, and it depends on what exactly the structure of this program should look like. One simple way would be to add a constructor to the MainWindow class that takes a pointer to `something` and stores that pointer as a member, i.e.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    ...
    MainWindow(Something* something) : something_ptr(something)
    {
    ...
    }
    ...
private:
    Something* something_ptr;
    ...
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_released()
    {
        something_ptr->stop();
    }
}
```

then from your main function:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Something something;
MainWindow w(&something);
something.start();
w.show();
```

Since you probably call `a.exec()` after this, something will exist until the application exits (since `exec()` is a blocking call).